# Does intersection of subgroups preserve the property of being generated by transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading a book and the author seems to just assume this proposition at one point, but upon trying it myself I don't see why it's the case, even though I can't find a counterexample.

**Statement:**
Let $U = U_1 \cap U_2$, where $U_1, U_2 \leq S_n$, the symmetric group, and $U_1, U_2$ are generated by transpositions. Then $U$ is also generated by transpositions.

The author assumes it in the case where $U_1$ is generated by transpositions of the form $(i, i+1)$, so at least that case should be true.

I don't really know where to start with this problem.
Writing $g = s_1s_2\cdots s_k = t_1t_2 \cdots t_l$, where $s_i \in U_1, t_i \in U_2$ are transpositions, I don't really know how to continue in order to find an expression of $g$ in terms of transpositions in $U_1 \cap U_2$.

A more general version of the statement that I also don't know whether it's true is:

**Statement:**
Let $U = U_1 \cap U_2$, where $U_1, U_2 \leq G$, some larger group, and let $T$ be a subset of $G$. Suppose $U_1$ is generated by $U_1\cap T$ and $U_2$ is generated by $U_2\cap T$. Then $U$ is generated by $U_1\cap U_2 \cap T$.

I don't see how to start with this one either.

Comment: What is the book, and where is this assumed?

Comment: @DavidSheard It's in the book on Hecke algebras and q-Schur algebras by Andrew Mathas. There's a lot of notation so I tried to distill it to its simplest form. It's on page 56, the proof of Lemma 4.3. I think the argument for "Therefore, H is generated by transpositions" is the argument I gave, but it's obfuscated by the notation of tableaux if you try to read just that part.
If I made a mistake of assumption I would be interested to know as well.

Comment: The general statement is false. Let $G=S_6$, $a=(1,2,3,4)$, $b=(1,2,3,4)(5,6)$, $U_1=\langle a\rangle$, $U_2 = \langle b \rangle$, $T=\{a,b\}$. Then $U_1 \cap U_2 = \langle a^2 \rangle$, which has empty intersection with $T$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you! How about if $T$ is a generator set of $G$?

Comment: The statement is true at least for the case of both $U_1$ and $U_2$ being generated by adjacent transpositions. In that case the subgroups are Young subgroups of $S_n$, and their intersection must then be another Young subgroup.

Comment: The same example but with $G = \langle T \rangle$. But the original question about subgroups generated by transpositions is interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Here I prove that the intersection of two subgroups of a symmetric group that are generated by transpositions is itself generated by transpositions.)

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$ generated by transpositions. We claim that $G$ is a product of the symmetric groups on the orbits of $G$. It suffices to do this in the case where $G$ is transitive, and here we may assume that $(1,2)$ lies in $G$. Let $\sim$ be the relation given by $i\sim j$ if and only if $(i,j)$ lies in $G$, including the case $(i,i)=1$. Then $\sim$ is reflexive and symmetric, and we claim it is transitive. But if $(i,j)$ and $(j,k)$ are in $G$, they generate the subgroup $\mathrm{Sym}(\{i,j,k\})$ of $G$, which contains $(i,k)$. Hence $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. But then $G$ contains all transpositions of $S_n$, so is $S_n$.

Thus $G$ is simply a direct product of the symmetric groups on the orbits of $G$, and thus we can easily understand the intersection of any two such subgroups. $i$ and $j$ lie in the same orbit of $G\cap H$ if and only if they lie in the same orbit of $G$ and of $H$, and $G\cap H$ is the product of symmetric groups on those orbits (since $(i,j)$ lies in $G\cap H$).

The general case, even where $T$ consists of the set of elements of order $2$, is false, and counterexamples are numerous. One is given in the other answer to the question.

Comment: This is a very nice and clear explanation!

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation!
In the book the statement is given in terms of products of symmetric groups already (plus some notation), so I guess in my attempt to simplify it to a very simple group theoretic question I made a trivial statement that was probably alright to skip for the author into a much harder two-step problem, and I couldn't see the solution as I was staring into my version.
So this clears up even what the author wanted me to see. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**The more general statement is not true**, even if you assume that $T$ is a set of elements of order $2$ like transpositions. For an explicit counter example, consider the dihedral group $D_8$ of order 16 which has presentation $$G=D_8=\langle s_1,s_2\mid s_1^2,\,s_2^2,\,(s_1s_2)^8\rangle.$$ Take as the set $T$ the set of all conjugates of $s_1$ and $s_2$ which all have order $2$. Thinking of $D_8$ as the group of symmetries of a regular octagon, the elements of $T$ are all of the reflectional symmetries.

Let $U_1$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{s_1,s_2s_1s_2\}\subset T$ which is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$. Similarly, let $U_2$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{s_2,s_1s_2s_1\}\subset T$ which is also isomorphic to $D_4$. However you can check that $U_1\cap U_2$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and consists of the rotations by multiples of $\pi/2$. Indeed $U_1\cap U_2\cap T=\emptyset$.

[image]

In fact this example is even closer to the case of $S_n$ than just the fact that $T$ consists of order $2$ elements. Both $S_n$ and $D_n$ are examples of Coxeter groups - groups generated by reflections. The set of transpositions in $S_n$ are the reflections in that case, and the set $T$ in my example above is the set of reflections for $D_n$.

**Answer to the main question:**
In this broader setting of Coxeter groups (or more accurately Coxeter systems) it is possible to justify the first statement in the case that $T$ is the set of transpositions of the form $(i\;i+1)$. With this particular choice of $T$, the pair $(S_n, T)$ is a Coxeter system. Writing $t_i=(i\;i+1)$ for $1\le i\le n-1$ then $S_n$ has the presentation $$\langle t_1,\dots, t_{n-1}\mid t_i^2\;\textrm{for}\; 1\le i\le n-1;\; (t_it_{i+1})^3\;\textrm{for}\; 1\le i\le n-2;\;\textrm{and} \;(t_it_j)^2\;\textrm{for}\; 1\le i\le n-1\;\textrm{such that}\;|i-j|\ge2\rangle.$$
(Compare the form of this presentation to the one above for $D_n$)

More generally a Coxeter system is a pair $(W,S)$ where $W$ is a group, $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}\subset W$ generates $W$, and $W$ has a presentation of the form $$\langle s_1,\dots,s_n\mid s_i^2 \;\textrm{for}\;1\le i\le n;\;(s_is_j)^{m_{ij}}\;\textrm{for}\;1\le i\neq j\le n\rangle,$$ for suitable chosen integers $m_{ij}$.

It is a basic result in the theory of Coxeter groups that if $S'\subset S$ then $\langle S'\rangle$ is a Coxeter group with Coxeter system $(\langle S'\rangle,S')$.

Applying that in the case of $(S_n,T)$ then there are subsets $T_1,T_2\subset T$ such that $U_i=\langle T_i\rangle$, and then $U=U_1\cap U_2=\langle T_1\cap T_2\rangle$ is generated by $U\cap T$.

For an introduction to Coxeter groups see [this set of notes](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301663425.pdf), and the general theorem I apply is given in Theorem 5.2 there.

Comment: Are the elements transpositions?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven No, my example is in the broader setting outside of the symmetric group. I saw you say you were writing a proof to the main question so decided just to leave my answer as a counter example to the second question

Comment: @DavidA.Craven There is one method of proof which sidesteps the details (although perhaps is not very useful unless you are familiar with Coxeter groups) I'll edit my answer to add it anyway

Comment: I have just remembered how to bypass it with an equivalence relation. But if you are going to do it that way then you should edit your answer instead.

Comment: No, I was going to appeal to a general theorem which says special subgroups of Coxeter groups are again Coxeter groups, so you should definitely add your answer too!

Comment: Thank you for your insightful counterexample!
I didn't expect the original statement to be that tight. 
I am certainly interested in Coxeter groups. Even if you don't write the full answer, could you perhaps state or link to the theorem you mentioned?

Comment: Edit added - the application of the theorem is sketched rather than being rigorous but I've linked to a fell treatment of the subject. In particular what I've stated above is part (i), but one also must use part (ii) from that theorem

Comment: That's a good refresher on Coxeter groups. I will check that resource in more detail later.
I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you for your help!